# How to make assciation of different kind of roles(agent and client)

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I am using devise as a user model with rolify for roles

A user has one role called 'client'

A user has one role called 'agent'

I want to make a association like this

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  rolify
  has_many :agents # if user role is client will get all agents
  has_many :clients # if user role is agent will get all clients
end
```

How to make above associations. Please help me.
Thanks

Comment: You should use the join table provide by Rolify, follow the docs it should appear clear: https://github.com/RolifyCommunity/rolify

Comment: How do you have any example for me

Comment: e.g. `user = User.find(1)` then `user.add_role :agent`. But based on your self answer you meant a user should have other users as agents or clients, which is a completely different issue.

Comment: I already mention it on association 'if user role is client will get all agents'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the above problem with following associations. Let me know if I am wrong

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  rolify
  has_many :user_agents
  has_many :agents, through: :user_agents # if user role is client will get all agents
  has_many :user_clients, class_name: 'UserAgent', foreign_key: :agent_id
  has_many :clients, source: :user, through: :user_clients # if user role is agent will get all clients
end
```

```
# field: user_id and agent_id
class UserAgent < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :agent, class_name: 'User'
end
```